# iPhone:similar to "where" type clause in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am using core data first time in my application for my problem I have done google a lot but I didn't find specific solution.

I have **Entity**:SubCategory

**Attributes**:mainCategoryId,subCategoryName.

Now I want to fetch the data like

```
Select subCategoryName from SubCategory where mainCategoryId=1;
```

The code which I have implemented is as follows:

```
 NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SubCategory" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SubCategoryName == %@",@"Triangular1"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    arrSubCategory = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

How can I fetch similar kind of data in coredata

share your ideas

thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you post any code which you have tried till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question what you need is,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mainCategoryId = %@",@"1"];
```

So your code will look like,

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
    entityForName:@"SubCategory" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mainCategoryId = %@",@"1"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"subCategoryName: %@", [info valueForKey:@"subCategoryName"]);
}
```

The above is just a sample code. Actual implementation could be different based on your requirement.

A tutorial on [coredata is here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started). Check that out as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
NSString *maincategoryId = @"1";
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"SubCategory"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rubriqueid == %@", maincategoryId]];
```

and after you call your NSMutableArray to put your result:

```
NSMutableArray *answensmuarray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```